# Library for visualizing object graphs in .NET

Tags: .net, visualization, object-graph

Does anyone know of, or can recommend, a library that can recursively visualize an arbitrary object graph in .NET?

I need to be able to print out (to the console) a formatted representation of an object graph. For example, given a simple object graph like this:

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.Bar = new Bar();
foo.Bar.Baz = 42;
foo.Bar.Qux = "quux";
foo.Corge = false;
```

It would be easy to produce output like this:

```
Foo:
    Bar:
        Baz: 42;
        Qux: "quux"
    Corge: false
```

I could definitely write such a library myself using Reflection, but if something like it already exists I might as well use it instead of wasting time on reinventing the wheel.

I need it to give coding demos, to easily show to an audience what a constructed object graph looks like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, this resembles JSON. You could use [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx). You could also try the [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) format which is pretty human readable and there are [some .NET libraries](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=yaml+c%23&aq=f&aqi=g3g-o1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=c6affe93747c32d0).

Comment: Yes, I ended up using Json.NET (http://json.codeplex.com/) which was good enough for my immediate purpose. However, I was wondering if there was something more general-purpose...

Answer (score 2):

FWIW I found that Visual Studio ships with an [Object Dumper sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397968.aspx) that does something very close to this.

However, I find the formatting less desirable than JSON, which I ended up using instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried linqpad? But then you would need to have your code in there, but that is also nice for demoing IMO.

Comment: I don't need a tool, but I library whose methods I can invoke from my own code to show off object graph structure. Can LinqPad be used in this way? AFACT it can't, but I may be mistaken...